# Is it ever explained why Gorons are allowed in Gerudo Town?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

There are two gorons inside Gerudo town, who were allowed inside Gerudo Town, despite being men. One of them even wonders himself why he was allowed entry in the first place.

Is it ever explained somewhere why they were allowed in? Like... are Gorons and Gerudo best buddies or something?

Comment: Quote from [Zeldapedia](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Goron): "Gorons are allowed into the Gerudo Town despite not being via (female). This could imply that the Gerudo may see Gorons as a single gender nature race, or this may be because Gorons are a non-human race."  Doesn't quite explain it, but it's a theory.

Comment: Well, tnx for the unexplained downvotes, whoever it was. What is wrong with the question?

Comment: Questions like this are often down voted on here. Some people may view it as a game design question which is off-topic, but I think historically, questions like this have just never been liked on Arqade since they dance around being on topic and since they aren't really related to gameplay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe another Gerudo in the town says that they are not sure whether the Gorons they let in are male or female. So, it seems to simply be that the Gerudo cannot tell the difference between male and female Gorons and err on the side of caution by letting them in.

Answer (score 8):

In the japanese version of the game, after you free Nabooris, a second Goron can be seen alongside Lyndae. Talk to them, and they will say "I made a new friend! But are they a boy friend or a girl friend?"

[image: A screenshot with part of the text above]

I stole the image above from [this Tumblr post](https://kaialone.tumblr.com/post/636034745630965760/the-reason-why-gorons-are-allowed-in-gerudo-town), which elaborates further on that.

So this was dropped from the English localization. It seems that Gorons are genderless. You may think of them as males because of their low voice and bulky, muscular bodies, but that is just appearances and first impressions.

Gerudo people apparently will accept genderless people among them since their rule is *no males allowed*. Having no gender is different from being male.

Answer (score 1):

I look everywhere in Gerudo Town and can't find why. however, I searched Goron City and found no female Goron... This might mean that Goron are genderless creatures and are thought of to be male as they have no female body parts. As they are not really male, they are therefore allowed in Gerudo Town.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).